# Jquery array isn't changed when json callback

Tags: php, jquery

I want to the arr1 value is changed to arr2 value(test.php) when click event is triggered. However, there is error on the following code.

Is there anyone can help me out? Thanks!

```
$(function(){
               var arr1 = ["apple","banana","orange"];

               $("input").click(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"test.php",
                          cache:false,
                          success: function(data) {
                                arr1 = data;
                              }
                          });
                });

    });
```

**-------Test.php----------------------------------------**

```
<?php   
    echo $arr2 =array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Toyota"); 

?>
```

Comment: Self-Duplicated [page doesn't show json callback value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927183/page-doesnt-show-json-callback-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to transfer complex objects to javascript. In php, you'd encode your array using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
<?php
    $arr2 = array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
    echo json_encode($arr2);
?>
```

Then you have to tell jquery to talk in json using `dataType: 'json'`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        arr1 = data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't manipulate same kind of data! You'll need to json_encode your php array

```
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

in order to fetch it as an array in your JS function

Comment: This alone won't work, after all it's just a string. You'll still have to decode it.

Comment: Just adding     dataType: "json" to be sure your manipulate json return, in JS side and it's already an array inside the success function ready to be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just echo. This is what you probably want to do

```
$arr2 = array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

Then on the Javascript side of things, use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: `getJSON()` won't work in the general case here. For his "test.php" it will, but that's just an example. It looks like here he is making a `POST` request, not a `GET` request. `getJSON()` only does `GET` requests. You have to use `ajax()` here with `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: While this might be the case, it is IMHO questionable whether it makes sense to use `POST` at all for this case, isn't it? This is just requesting a resource.

Comment: In this case you wouldn't use POST, but I assume that was just a minimal test case. If the actual case is a GET, then either method will work.